# Cannot pass data to the as.net mvc controller from $http in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am Getting null value in action method when i am pass data from angular js to action method. data is coming up to $scope.custmodel and i debug and see it hit to the AddCutomer method but data is null. can anyone help me to fix this issue

Admin.js code

```
var app = angular.module("adminmdl", [])
app.controller("admincontroller", function ($scope,AdminService) {
    $scope.Action = 'Add';
    $scope.data = {
        cus_code: '',
        cus_name: '' 
    }
    $scope.savecu = function () {
        AdminService.saveCustomerDdetails($scope.cusmodel).then(function (data) {

            if (data != null) {
                alert('Insert successfully');
            } else {
                alert('error in inerting data');
            }
        });
    }
})
.factory("AdminService", function ($http) {

    var fact = {};
    fact.saveCustomerDdetails = function (d) {
        return $http({
            url: '/Admin/AddCutomer',
            method: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(d),
            headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
        });
    };
    return fact;
});
```

ASP MVC Method

```
   [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult AddCutomer(Customer customer) {
                te.Customers.Add(customer);
                te.SaveChanges();
                string message = "Success";
            return new JsonResult { Data = message, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };


        }
```

html code

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="#" name="basic_validate" id="basic_validate" novalidate="novalidate">

                                 <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Customer Code</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="text" ng-model="cusmodel.Customercode" name="required" id="required" >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Customer Name</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="text" ng-model="cusmodel.Customername" name="name" id="name" >
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Save" ng-click="savecu()" class="btn btn-success">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Clear" class="btn btn-success" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: don't use JSON.stringify just put d in data

Comment: FYI: JSON.stringtify() is used for convert JSON format to string if your backend consumes JSON from the request so no need to use JSON.stringtify()

Answer (score 0):

add [FromBody] attribute to the controller as shown below

public JsonResult AddCutomer([FromBody] Customer customer)

Comment: [FromBody]  can use only for web api this method is not web api its normal mvc. i tired but its not working @SrikanthB